# Defining pure function @ vs /@

Tags: pure-function

Learning how to program I dont fully get the difference of /@ vs @

```
l = Table[n (n + 1) (n + 2) (n + 3), {n, 1, 10}]
{24, 120, 360, 840, 1680, 3024, 5040, 7920, 11880, 17160}

Sqrt[l + 1]
{5, 11, 19, 29, 41, 55, 71, 89, 109, 131}
```

Trying to obtain the same result

```
a = (#^(1/2)) &@ (# + 1) & /@ l
{5, 11, 19, 29, 41, 55, 71, 89, 109, 131}

b = (#^(1/2)) & /@ (# + 1) & /@ l
{25, 121, 361, 841, 1681, 3025, 5041, 7921, 11881, 17161}

c = (#^(1/2)) & /@ (# + 1) & @ l
{5, 11, 19, 29, 41, 55, 71, 89, 109, 131}
```

The way I understand /@ is to apply the function to every item of the list, so not sure why I get different results on a, b, c.  Particularly why in b the function `(#^(1/2)) &`  is not evaluated at all

Comment: `Sqrt[# + 1] & /@ l`

Comment: Since you said that you are a beginner, I'd strongly recommend you studying [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice). I have it saved in my favorites and every now and then I glance at it, and every time I learn something new.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three things at play here:

- The precedence of `@`,`/@` and `&` (note the parentheses):

  ```
  HoldForm[#&@#&/@l]
  HoldForm[#&/@#&@l]
  HoldForm[#&/@#&/@l]
  (* ((#1&)[#1]&)/@l *)
  (* ((#1&)/@#1&)[l] *)
  (* ((#1&)/@#1&)/@l *)
  ```
- The `Listable` attribute of functions like `Plus` and `Power`:

  ```
  1+#&@{x,y}
  #^2&@{x,y}
  (* {1+x,1+y} *)
  (* {x^2,y^2} *)
  ```
- The behavior of `Map` applied to atomic expressions: (*note*: does not apply to all types: e.g. `Association` and `SparseArray` are handled differently - thanks @Alan for pointing this out)

  ```
  f /@ {x, y}
  f /@ x
  (* {f[x], f[y]} *)
  (* x *)
  ```

Putting everything together, you can easily explain what you're seeing (I'll leave it as an exercise to explain the individual cases)

Comment: You final point needs rephrasing, I believe.  E.g., an association `a = <|x -> 1, y -> 2|>` is atomic (`AtomQ@a==True`) but 
`f /@ a` maps over the values.

Comment: @Alan Thanks, completely forgot about that part - I've added a note